# How to use Dapper to write raw SQL and map to a entity class using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dapper, rawsql

I want to write raw SQL to get a result sets from a set of tables where there is 1-to-M relationship.

I am using Dapper for this, but not getting the expected results.

The first table is `Supplier`:

```
    public class Supplier: IId
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Ref{ get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
        public List<Category> Categories{ get; set; }
        public int? Ticket { get; set; }
    }
```

Then there's `Category`:

```
    public class Category: IId
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int SupplierId{ get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore] public Supplier Supplier{ get; set; }
        public Type Type { get; set; }
        public Status Status { get; private set; }
        public string CompletedBy { get; private set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; private set; }
        public DateTime? CreatedOn { get; private set; }
        public int? Ticket { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is my SQL:

```
var reference = 5055;

var sql = "SELECT S.Ref,S.CreatedOn,S.Ticket" +
          "       C.TaskId AS 'Id', C.SupplierId, C.Type, C.Status, C.CompletedBy, C.CreatedBy, C.CreatedOn, C.Ticket " + 
          "FROM Category C " +
          "INNER JOIN Supplier S ON S.SupplierId = C.SupplierId " +
          "WHERE S.Ref = @reference ";

 var parameters = new {reference};

 var suppliers = connection.QueryAsync<Supplier, List<Category>, Supplier>(sql, (supplier,category)   => {
                    supplier.Categories = category;
                    return supplier;
                }, parameters, splitOn: "Id" );

var result = suppliers.Result.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedOn).FirstOrDefault();
```

What I want is categories should be included in supplier entity, I read the documentation for Dapper and from that I tried the code shown here, but it's not working out.

Can anybody help me with this?

Can anybody tell me another approach for this, for example with a SQL view or a stored procedure?

Comment: I think you want `QueryAsync<Supplier, Category, Supplier>` and `(supplier,category)   => { supplier.Categories.Add(category); return supplier; }`

Comment: @Charlieface: You're on the right path, but that will create as many suppliers as there are categories and they will only have one category each. The normal way to solve this is to add the suppliers to a dictionary.

Comment: Yup forgot that, you want `(supplier,category)   => { if (!dict.TryGetValue(supplier.Id, out var sup)) dict[supplier.Id] = sup = supplier; sup.Categories.Add(category); return sup; }`

Comment: @Charlieface not  able to understand can you please elaborate

Comment: One thing I would do is replace the `.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedOn).FirstOrDefault()` expressions by including that as part of the SQL. That is, add a `TOP 1` to the front of the `SELECT` list and put an `ORDER BY s.CreatedOn DESC` clause at the end of the query. You might still want to keep the `FirstOrDefault()` part of the expression for type system reasons, but this way you prevent the code from ever trying to put more than the one record into memory on the DB server or from wanting to transfer more than the one record over the wire between the server and the client.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn what about suppliers with multiple categories?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code that was outlined in the comments. The basic idea is that since the query will return multiple rows for the same "Supplier"-instance the Dictionary will make sure that only one instance is actually created and will be reused in subsequent result rows.

```
 Dictionary<int, Supplier> dict = new Dictionary<int, Supplier>();

 var suppliers = connection.QueryAsync<Supplier, Category, Supplier>(sql,
    (s, c) =>
    {
        if (!dict.TryGetValue(s.Id, out var supplier))
        {
            // Haven't seen this supplier before -> add to dictionary and initialize Categories list
            dict[s.Id] = s;
            s.Categories = new List<Category>();
            supplier = s;
        }

        supplier.Categories.Add(c);
        return supplier;
    },
 parameters, splitOn: "Id");
```

Answer (score 0):

how i found a way to solve this is

```
var reference = 5055;

var sql = "SELECT S.SupplierId As 'Id',S.Ref,S.CreatedOn,S.Ticket " +
          "FROM Supplier S " +
          "WHERE S.Ref = @reference ";

 var parameters = new {reference};

 var suppliers = connection.QueryFirstOrDefault<Supplier>(sql, parameters);

 suppliers.Category =  (List<Category>) connection.Query<Category>("SELECT C.CategoryId As 'Id',C.SupplierId,C.Type,C.Status,C.CompletedBy,C.CompletedOn,C.CreatedBy,C.CreatedOn,C.Ticket FROM Category C WHERE C.SupplierId= @supplierId", new { supplierId = suppliers.Id});
            return suppliers;
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 0):

```
//try this using look-up dictionary.

var lookup = new Dictionary<int, Supplier>();
connection.Query<Supplier, Category, Supplier>(sql, (s, c) =>
   {
       Supplier supplier;
       if (!lookup.TryGetValue(c.Id, out supplier))
           lookup.Add(c.Id, supplier = s);
       if (supplier.Categories == null)
           supplier.Categories = new List<Category>();
       supplier.Categories.Add(c);
       return supplier;
   }, parameters).AsQueryable();
   var resultList = lookup.Values;
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**